# Chicago style references in latex

Tags: bibliographies, chicago-style

I have to use chicago reference style for my thesis references. Below are two example references can anyone tell me which exactly is chicago style.

> Gao, G. and K. Whitehouse (2009). The self-programming thermostat:
>   optimizing setback schedules based on home occupancy patterns. In
>   Proceedings of the First ACM Workshop on Embedded Sensing Systems for
>   Energy-Eciency in Buildings, pp. 67{72. ACM.

OR

> Ge Gao and Kamin Whitehouse. The self-programming thermostat: opti-
>   mizing setback schedules based on home occupancy patterns. In
>   Proceedings of the First ACM Workshop on Embedded Sensing Systems for
>   Energy-Eciency in Buildings, pages 67{72. ACM, 2009.

I need to use the first one the chicago style. But I am not able to generate reference numbers with the 1st option shown.

I am using the following latex packages

```
\bibliographystyle{Classes/CUEDbiblio}
\bibliographystyle{Classes/jmb}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat} %this works with package natbib

\bibliographystyle{Classes/chicago} % bibliography style
\renewcommand{\bibname}{References} % changes default name Bibliography to References
%\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
\bibliography{References/references} % References file
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{References} %adds References to contents page
```

Can anyone help me? how to solve this issue

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: As far as I know, CMS is an author-year style or there is a notes version. So I'm not sure what numbers you are trying to generate. In any case, why are you declaring 4 different bibliography styles? I'm not really clear about what you are doing or need to do. (First you seem to be asking which of 2 styles *is* Chicago. Then you seem to be saying that the first is Chicago and asking how to achieve it.)

Comment: `biblatex-chicago` is designed for this purpose.

Comment: @cfr - The default form of citation callouts with the `chicago` style is definitely `authoryear`. However, it's straightforward to generate numeric-style citation callouts by loading the `natbib` citation management package with the option `numbers`.

Comment: Of the examples in the question or the one in the answer, none are in Chicago style.

Answer (score 5):

The first of the two options is pretty much "chicago" style. It's not clear to me which problem you're looking to solve, but I have the impression that it is that you need numeric-style rather than authoryear-style citation call-outs. If this impression is correct, you can achieve your objective by loading the `natbib` citation management package with the option `numbers`:

```
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{chicago}
```

The output of a full MWE (minimum working example):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{references.bib}
@inproceedings{xyz,
author    = "Ge Gao and Kamin Whitehouse",
title     = "The Self-Programming Thermostat: Optimizing Setback 
             Schedules based on Home Occupancy Patterns",
booktitle = "Proceedings of the First ACM Workshop on Embedded 
             Sensing Systems for Energy-Efficiency in Buildings", 
pages     =  "67-72", 
publisher = "ACM", 
year      = 2009,
}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib} % omit 'numbers' option if authoryear-style citation callouts are needed
\bibliographystyle{chicago} % bibliography style
\begin{document}
According to \cite{xyz}, \ldots

\bibliography{references} % bib entries are in 'references.bib'
\end{document}
```